# Using Apache Solr to do faceted search for unstructured text

Tags: solr

I have a set of text documents that I have indexed in my respective collection defined in Solr. I am able to do a keyword based search that returns the required documents having the typed in keyword. But my next objective is to do faceted search on unstructured text wherein I am able to retrieve results based on facet fields.

I have tried the following steps:
1) I have defined a new field (distributioncompany)in managed-schema that will act as facet field with a copyfield also defined (distributioncompany_str). But when I do indexing curl command ( with id and distribution company name passed as arguments), I get the facet counts with q =*, but doesnot work when I type in a keyword in q field.
2) I also tried text tagger feature with a tag field defined for te facet field so that required entity can be extracted from document and matched against a list of tag values. But tag field not getting returned

For 1st approach:
1)

```
curl -X POST -H  ‘Content-type:text/plain’ –data-binary ‘{“add-field”:{“name”:”distributioncompany_str”,”type”:”string”,”multiValued”:true,
“indexed”:true,”stored”:false}}’
http://localhost:8983/solr/collectionname/schema
```

(same code used for adding distributioncompany field)
2) Copy field added:

```
curl -X POST -H  ‘Content-type:text/plain’ –data-binary ‘{“add-copy-field”:{“source”:”distributioncompany”,”dest”:”distributioncompany_str”}}’
http://localhost:8983/solr/collectionname/schema
```

3) Added a new document to index:

```
curl ‘http://localhost:8983/solr/collectionname/update/json/docs’ -H ‘Content-type:text/plain’ -d ‘{“id”:”Appeal No. 220 of 2013.pdf.txt”,”distributioncompany”:”Himachal Pradesh State Electricity Board”}’
```

But if query is done using q =*, it shows facet field count, but if query done using a keyword present in the document, it doesnot show up

For 2nd approach ( text tagger)
1) Added a new fieldtype "tag" in schema of collection
2) Added new fields ( a) trancompany (type:text_general),b) trancompany_tag(type:tag), c) copyfield for these 2 fields
3) Added a new custom SolrRequest Handler in Solrconfig file:

```
curl -X POST -H ‘Content-type:application/json’ http://192.168.0.95:8983/solr/rajdhanitest2/config -d ‘{
“add-requesthandler”:{
“name”:”/tag”,
“class”:”solr.TaggerRequestHandler”,
“defaults”:{“field”:” trancompany_tag”}
}
}’
```

4) Updates values for tag field "trancompany_tag" with curl command
5) But on passing text with one of tag values updated, only id gets returned not the tag value

For both approaches, the required faceted/ tagged field to be extracted from text document is not displayed when search query is done. Would appreciate help in guiding me how to do a faceted search for unstructured text documents

Comment: You're using a `string` field type. That means that the field isn't being processed any further, and thus, will only give a hit if you query for the _exact value_ that has been indexed. Use a text field if you want processing to happen (i.e. for the text to be split into separate tokens for each word, etc.).

Comment: Thanks Mats for your response. I have defined distributioncompany as text field and the copyfield distributioncompany_str as string. Even if I give an exact value match, it works when q=* but doesnot when i query it for a particular keyword.  For indexing the require document, I have used the following code: curl ‘http://192.168.0.95:8983/solr/rajdhanitest2/update/json/docs’ -H ‘Content-type:text/plain’ -d ‘{“id”:”Appeal No. 220 of 2013.pdf.txt”,”distributioncompany”:”Himachal Pradesh State Electricity Board”}’

Comment: Am I doing something wrong here while indexing? Since it is an unstructured text document, how would Solr extract the required field value and map it to facet field if I don't explicitly mention the field name during indexing? Would appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Does `distributioncompany:pradesh` give you any hits? If you're not including a field name, the default search field will be used - which is a field named `text` by default iirc. If there's no content copied into that field, you won't get any hits. You can supply `df` to set the default search field in a request, or use the edismax handler and `qf`. You'll have to use an explicit field name so you know what fields to search, yes. Include an example of the document being returned when querying for `*:*` and what query you're using that doesn't return anything.

Comment: When I query with q=*:* and facet field :distributioncompany and fq=distributioncompany_str:"Himachal Pradesh State Electricity Board", I get the following response:

Comment: "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"Appeal No. 220 of 2013.pdf.txt",
        "distributioncompany":["Himachal Pradesh State Electricity Board"],
        "distributioncompany_str":["Himachal Pradesh State Electricity Board"],
        "_version_":1644204542660706304}]
  },
  "facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{},
    "facet_fields":{
      "distributioncompany":[
        "board",1,
        "electricity",1,
        "himachal",1,
        "pradesh",1,
        "state",1,
        "nadu",0,
        "tamil",0]},

Comment: But if query with q=REC ( one of the terms present in the document returned above (Appeal No. 220 of 2013.pdf.txt), I get numFound as 0: "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  },
  "facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{},
    "facet_fields":{
      "distributioncompany":[
        "board",0,
        "electricity",0,
        "himachal",0,
        "nadu",0,
        "pradesh",0,
        "state",0,
        "tamil",0]},   . So it works for a universal search but not if I key in a searchword. I have defined 2 fields : one as text and other as string and joined them as copyfield.

Comment: Am I missing a trick here for faceted search for unstructured text? Please let me know.

Comment: As I said, it'll depend on which field you're searching against. If you're creating a query against your `_str` field, only exact matches will return a hit. If you're not including a field name in front of your query (and you should not provide the `fq` in that case), the default field will be used - which probably doesn't have any content in your case. Make the query explicit against the field name you want to search to find out why you're not getting any hits. Faceting doesn't do anything if there are no documents to create facet information for.

Comment: Thanks Mats. I queried using q=distributioncompany_str:"Himachal Pradesh State Electricity Board". It returns the corresponding document id.  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"Appeal No. 220 of 2013.pdf.txt",
        "distributioncompany":["Himachal Pradesh State Electricity Board"],
        "distributioncompany_str":["Himachal Pradesh State Electricity Board"],
        "_version_":1644204542660706304}]. I guess it means this document is present with required id and distribution company returned.

Comment: Correct, but if you want to get hits without giving the complete entry, you use the field that has processing attached. So you'd query `distributioncompany:pradesh` which should give you hits containing `pradesh` as long as you've used a text field with a proper analysis chain attached.

Comment: My objective is to search for a keyword present in the document like q="Renewable Energy Certificate" and then use distributioncompany as facet field, so that I get all documents having this keyword in their content. I am using this command to index the document: curl ‘http://192.168.0.95:8983/solr/rajdhanitest2/update/json/docs’ -H ‘Content-type:text/plain’ -d ‘{“id”:”Appeal No. 220 of 2013.pdf.txt”,”distributioncompany”:”Himachal Pradesh State Electricity Board”}’. Not sure where am I going wrong?

Comment: You're going to have to search against the processed field and not the one requiring exact hits. If you want to drop the field name from the search string, you have to set the `df=distributioncompany` (default field) as I mentioned above, or use the edismax query handler (`defType=edismax`) together with `qf=distributioncompany`. The `_str` field is only useful if you want to get _exact matches only_.

Comment: Didnot get the last point Mats. Let me explain the scenario: If a text document has a term called "Renewable Energy Certificate" as well as "Himachal Pradesh State Electricity Board" and the user wants to retrieve document having "Renewable Energy Certificate" but only where distributioncompany is "Himachal Pradesh State Electricity Board". So I have defined distributioncompany field in schema along with a copyfield for it. And while indexing, passing  "Himachal Pradesh State Electricity Board" explicitly. When I had done a plain indexing with schemaless configuration, it returned the result

Comment: But now since I want a filtered search with faceting, giving me the documents having keyword "Renewable Energy Certificate" for documents with distributioncompany value as "Himachal Pradesh State Electricity Board", it doesnot work if i key in Renewable Energy Certificate and give facet.field as distributioncompany.

Comment: Mats, I am thinking, Shall I use a fmap.content field to extract entire content of text document into 1 field say documentbody and also pass distributioncompany field value while indexing? So then in q, I can pass q=documentbody:"Renewable Energy Certificate" and fq=distributioncompany:Pradesh.

Comment: Thinking of trying the following curl command for this indexing: curl ‘http://192.168.0.95:8983/solr/rajdhanitest2/update/extract?literal.id=163_of_2015&uprefix=attr_&fmap.content=documentbody&commit=true’ –data-binary ‘[{“id”:”163_of_2005.pdf.txt”,”distributioncompany”:”Himachal Pradesh State Electricity Board”}]’.

Comment: I get the issue now. The way I am indexing the text document using curl command curl ‘192.168.0.95:8983/solr/rajdhanitest2/update/json/docs’ -H ‘Content-type:text/plain’ -d ‘{“id”:”Appeal No. 220 of 2013.pdf.txt”,”distributioncompany”:”Himachal Pradesh State Electricity Board”}’. This doesnot index the document content into text field ( Default field that stores document content).

Comment: Can anyone help me with the command to index a text document in Solr that will also let me pass a value for another field explicitly. E.g: If the document has a term called DERC and I want to map it to a facet field "distributioncompany" while doing faceted search, how do I pass this during indexing? Would appreciate any help on this